# Extracting the least area image around a Shapely polygon, with rotation allowed

Tags: python, polygon, shapely, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I have a Shapely polygon

```
polygon_geom = shapely.wkt.loads(feat['wkt'])
```

such as:

[image]

I can map it onto an image

```
polygon_pts = np.array(list(polygon_geom.exterior.coords))
plt.imshow(img_array_pre)
plt.plot(polygon_pts[:,0], polygon_pts[:,1])
```

[image]

A naive extraction of the image under the polygon looks like this:

[image]

I really want to get the least area extraction of the image under the polygon, with rotation allowed.  The result would look like this:

[image]

Is there an operation in Shapely or CV2 or skimage or similar Python package which does this?

This image is from the [xView2 challenge](https://xview2.org/).  The xView image set contains 162787 building annotations expressed as polygons.  The side length of a square bounding box enclosing these polygons is distributed as follows:

[image: Side length of polygon bounding box]

The distribution shows a long tail of large area chips, which incorporate multiple buildings in most cases.  90 out of 162,787 chips, or about 0.05%, are in the long tail.  The objective here is to minimize the tail, or in other words to reduce the number of chips containing multiple buildings, by reorienting the bounding box.  This tail may or may not be material for machine learning purposes, but it seems better to minimize it if possible.

Comment: This appears to be identical to the [Oriented Bounding Box](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133327/how-to-calculate-the-oriented-bounding-box-obb-of-a-polygon-or-point-set) problem, already answered.

Comment: See also https://geidav.wordpress.com/2014/01/23/computing-oriented-minimum-bounding-boxes-in-2d/

Comment: Duplicate question I think: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222403/how-to-find-the-minimum-perimeter-oriented-bounding-box

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this image, [Hurricane Harvey 17](https://xview2.org/).  It has a big diagonally oriented bounding polygon over a stadium:

[image]

obtained as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import shapely.wkt
import json

img_path='/home/catskills/Desktop/dataxv2/xBD/hurricane-harvey/images/hurricane-harvey_00000017_post_disaster.png'
img_path_pre=img_path.replace('_post_', '_pre_')
img_array_pre=np.array(Image.open(img_path_pre))
img_obj = Image.open(img_path)
img_array = np.array(img_obj)
label_path = img_path.replace('png', 'json').replace('images', 'labels')
label_file = open(label_path)
label_data = json.load(label_file)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(img_array_pre)
for feat in label_data['features']['xy']:
        try:
            damage_type = feat['properties']['subtype']
        except: # pre-disaster damage is default no-damage
            damage_type = "no-damage"
            continue
        polygon_geom= shapely.wkt.loads(feat['wkt'])
        polygon_pts = np.array(list(polygon_geom.exterior.coords))
        if feat['properties']['uid']=='529fbc55-a095-4b6a-a8f7-9cc9a93a5b44':
            plt.plot(polygon_pts[:,0], polygon_pts[:,1], linewidth=3.0)
            break
```

From the building mask polygon let's [obtain this bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654289/scipy-create-2d-polygon-mask):

[image]

as follows:

```
from matplotlib.path import Path
width, height=1024, 1024
poly_path=Path(polygon_pts)
x, y = np.mgrid[:height, :width]
coors=np.hstack((x.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1,1)))
mask = poly_path.contains_points(coors).reshape(height, width).T
plt.imshow(mask);
```

Then let's get the image under the mask:

[image]

as follows:

```
img_masked=np.zeros(img_array_pre.shape,dtype=img_array_pre.dtype)
img_masked[mask]=img_array_pre[mask]
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.imshow(img_masked);
plt.ylim(1023,425)
plt.xlim(150,850)
```

Using [David Butterworth's code for minimum-area bounding rectangle](https://github.com/dbworth/minimum-area-bounding-rectangle), let's find the smallest rectangle enclosing the bounding polygon:

[image]

as follows:

```
from qhull_2d import *
from min_bounding_rect import *
xy_points=polygon_pts
hull_points = qhull2D(xy_points)
hull_points = hull_points[::-1]
(rot_angle, area, width, height, center_point, corner_points) = minBoundingRect(hull_points)
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.plot(polygon_pts[:,0], polygon_pts[:,1])
plt.plot(corner_points[:,0], corner_points[:,1], color='red')
plt.ylim(1200,400)
plt.xlim(150,850)
```

Let's find a [projective transformation which maps the off-axis quadrilateral bounding box to a unit square bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283088/transform-irregular-quadrilateral-to-rectangle-in-python-matplotlib):

[image]

as follows:

```
from skimage.transform import ProjectiveTransform
t = ProjectiveTransform()
src = corner_points[0:-1]
dst = np.asarray([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0]])
if not t.estimate(src, dst): raise Exception("estimate failed")
data_local=t(polygon_pts)
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.plot(dst[[0,1,2,3,0], 0], dst[[0,1,2,3,0], 1], '-')
plt.plot(data_local.T[0], data_local.T[1])
```

Finally,run the transform in reverse from the target chip back to the source chip (which avoids creating holes in the projected image due to roundoff error on pixel locations, versus running the transform forward) as follows:

```
H=np.ceil(height).astype(int)
W=np.ceil(width).astype(int)
chip=np.zeros((H+1,W+1,3)).astype(img_masked.dtype)
x2, y2 = np.mgrid[:H, :W]
crds=np.hstack((x2.reshape(-1, 1), y2.reshape(-1,1))).astype(int)
crds1 = crds/np.array([H,W])
scrds=np.minimum(np.round(t.inverse(crds1)[:,::-1]).astype(int), 1023)
for i in range(scrds.shape[0]):
    (xt,yt)=crds[i]
    (xs,ys)=scrds[i]
    pixel=img_masked[xs,ys]
    chip[xt,yt]=pixel
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.imshow(chip)
```

yielding finally the desired result:

[image]